# Calling asynctask from handler android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having problems while doing some test for a new app.
I have an activity in which I execute an asynctask to communicate with my server and ask for a json file.

I want that this file is downloaded periodically (don't know, 3-4 seconds) so I created a handler in my activity to execute it each time.

It works fine with Logs but whenever I try to execute asynctask, it makes an exception saying:

```
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:576)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at com.mobile.myPacket.mySecondActivity.askForData(mySecondActivity.java:68)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at com.mobile.myPacket.mySecondActivity.access$000(mySecondActivity.java:22)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at com.mobile.myPacket.mySecondActivity$1.run(mySecondActivity.java:56)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-19 10:16:41.510: WARN/System.err(9051): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think it is because it is another thread and second call is making a problem with the first one. But I don't know how to solve it.

This is my activity:

```
            package com.mobile.myPacket;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.os.Handler;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import com.mobile.clases.AsyncResponse;
            import com.mobile.clases.MyTask;


            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import org.json.JSONArray;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;

            public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse {

                private String urlServer = "url";
                MyTask asyncTask =new MyTask();
                Handler handler = new Handler();


                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    handler.post(sendData);
                    setContentView(R.layout.secondActivity);
                    asyncTask.delegate = this;
                    //We ask for data the first time
                    askForData();
                }


                @Override
                public void processFinish(JSONArray output) {    //Executed from asyncTask
                    //Data received
                    Log.i("TEST", output.toString());
                }

                @Override
                protected void onDestroy() {
                    super.onDestroy();
                    handler.removeCallbacks(sendData);
                }

                private final Runnable sendData = new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            //prepare and send the data here..

                            askForData();
                           //Log.i("TEST","aa");
                                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                private void askForData(){
                    Log.i("TEST","askForData");
                    asyncTask.execute(urlServer+"test.php");
                }


            }
```

Without handler, asyncTask works fine just one time. So I guess that class is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute the same `AsyncTask` multiple times.

Before executing the `AsyncTask`, instantiate a new instance first:

```
private void askForData(){
    asyncTask = new MyTask();
    asyncTask.delegate = this;
    asyncTask.execute(urlServer+"test.php");
}
```

Also remove the instantiation of the `AsyncTask` at the beginning of your class.